# Using different mongo database than admin in sails

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm struggling to connect with sails to a mongodb database that uses a database for authentication named "dbadmin". Where I am DBA decided to have all users centralized in a users database.

I can connect to this "dbadmin" database but then sails complains it cannot create collections there.

How can I use an authentication database and then a different database for collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using the URL for the connection has more possibilities. So all I had to do is append at the end `authSource=dbadmin`

```
module.exports = {

    models: {
        connection: 'mongoRM'
    },

    connections: {
        mongoRM: {
            adapter: 'sails-mongo',
            url: 'mongodb://user:password@db_url:port/database?authSource=dbadmin'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two database connection in your connections config file and then you can pass the connection in your data model directly 
see the example:

in your config file
// server/config/connections.js

```
 dbadmin: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'dbadmin-host',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'username', 
    password: 'password', 
    database: 'dbadmin'
  }

 dbuser: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'dbuser-host',
    port: 27017,
    user: 'username', 
    password: 'password', 
    database: 'dbuser'
  }
```

and now you can use in your model:
// server/api/models/AdminUser.js

```
module.exports = {  
  connection:'dbadmin',
  attributes: {

    name : { type: 'string' },

    pass : { type: 'string' }
  }
};
```

// server/api/models/Users.js

```
module.exports = {  
  connection:'dbuser',
  attributes: {

    name : { type: 'string' },

    pass : { type: 'string' }
  }
};
```

NOTE: you can not make any collection between this two model .

Comment: Thanks for your example but I was talking about using a different database to authenticate users rather than using two different databases.